# 'can only join iterable' when fetching data using tia.bbg.datamgr (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, numpy, data-management

I'm writing a script that fetches data from Bloomberg using the TIA toolkit. I'm trying to place the `PX_VALUE` from the `start` date for each equity in `stocks` in a dictionary called `dict1` so that i can manipulate those values later.
Here is my script so far without the calculations:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import tia
import tia.bbg.datamgr as dm
from operator import itemgetter

start = datetime.date(2017, 1, 3)
end = datetime.date(2017, 7, 25)

diffdays = ((end - start).days)/365
resolution = 0.01
diff2dp = int(np.round(diffdays/resolution))*resolution
diff = 1/diff2dp

dict1 = {}

stocks = ('GOOGL US Equity','MSFT US Equity', 'IBM US Equity')
mgr = dm.BbgDataManager()
eqt = mgr[stocks]

for eq in eqt:
    df = eq.get_historical(['PX_LAST'], start, end)
    k = df.loc[start]['PX_LAST']
    dict1 [stocks] = k

print dict1
```

And here is the actual Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bloomberg\Desktop\examples\CAGR by LouisV2 BROKEN.py", line 23, in <module>
    for eq in eqt:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\datamgr.py", line 94, in __getitem__
    return self.get_attributes(flds, **self.overrides)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\datamgr.py", line 90, in get_attributes
    frame = self.mgr.get_attributes(self.sids, flds, **overrides)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\datamgr.py", line 148, in get_attributes
    return self.terminal.get_reference_data(sids, flds, **overrides).as_frame()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\v3api.py", line 745, in get_reference_data
    return self.execute(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\v3api.py", line 711, in execute
    self.logger.info('executing request: %s' % repr(request))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\v3api.py", line 432, in __repr__
    fields=','.join(self.fields),
TypeError: can only join an iterable
>>>
```

I have also written a script that works for 1 equity with the calculations:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import tia
import tia.bbg.datamgr as dm

start = datetime.date(2017, 1, 3)
end = datetime.date(2017, 7, 25)

diffdays = ((end - start).days)/365
resolution = 0.01
diff2dp = int(np.round(diffdays/resolution))*resolution
diff = 1/diff2dp

mgr = dm.BbgDataManager()
eqt = mgr['GOOGL US Equity']
datafetch = eqt.get_historical(['PX_LAST'], start, end)
calc1 = ((datafetch.loc[end]['PX_LAST'])/(datafetch.loc[start]['PX_LAST']))
calc2 = (pow(calc1,diff))-1
calc22dp = int(np.round(calc2/resolution))*resolution

print calc22dp
```

Comment: You need to show us the complete stack trace. Without it, it is very hard to see where the problem is.

Comment: @BoarGules Sorry, I have added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your single-security solution does this:

```
eqt = mgr['GOOGL US Equity']
```

but your multiple-security solution does (in effect) this:

```
eqt = mgr[('GOOGL US Equity','MSFT US Equity', 'IBM US Equity')]
```

Now, I obviously cannot test this without a Bloomberg installation, but it is clear from the error message that your problem is with `eqt`. Are you 100% sure you can pass a tuple of BBG ids as a key to `dm.BbgDataManager()`? The results you are getting suggests that you can't.

Follow the line of your working one-security solution, but looping through the stocks of interest:

```
stocks = ('GOOGL US Equity','MSFT US Equity', 'IBM US Equity')  
mgr = dm.BbgDataManager()
for stock in stocks: 
    eqt = mgr[stock]
    datafetch = eqt.get_historical(['PX_LAST'], start, end)
    calc1 = ((datafetch.loc[end]['PX_LAST'])/(datafetch.loc[start]['PX_LAST']))
    calc2 = (pow(calc1,diff))-1
    calc22dp = int(np.round(calc2/resolution))*resolution
    print calc22dp
```

Comment: Ok so I implemented that as you suggested and it Displays the names of all 3 equities but with only one value `-0.21` which is the value of only IBM.

Comment: So maybe every time the calculation finishes it overwrites the previous results?

Comment: It looks like you didn't put the `print` statement inside the loop. If you only print results after the loop finishes then obviously you will only print the final values. I didn't realize I needed to be that specific.

Comment: Sorry but I'm quite new to this, tabbed it in and it works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: If the solution worked for you then please accept it.